# Apache mod_python with django issue

Tags: django, apache2, mod-python

While running a django application on top of apache2 mod_python, I am getting this error message in my apache error log.

```
[Tue Dec 14 14:26:45 2010] [error] [client SOME_IP] IOError: Write failed, client closed connection., referer: http://example.com/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1931, in ReportError
    req.write(text)
IOError: Write failed, client closed connection.
[Tue Dec 14 14:26:45 2010] [error] [client SOME_IP] python_handler: Dispatch() returned non-integer., referer: http://example.com/
```

Can anyone please suggest some solution on this?

Comment: try ask on serverfault.com ;)

Comment: What Python/Apache/mod_python/Django version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better long-term solution is to not use mod_python, since mod_python is no longer in development, and will not be supported in future versions of Django. Consider using [mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) instead.

The [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/) has this to say about mod_python:

> Support for mod_python has been deprecated, and will be removed in Django 1.5. If you are configuring a new deployment, you are strongly encouraged to consider using mod_wsgi or any of the other supported backends.

Answer (score 1):

Indicates that the user HTTP client connection was dropped before the complete response could be written back. Nothing one can do about it. Your application should handle it gracefully.